# What are these {{ }} for in html

Tags: html, flask

I found out that these `{{}}` can directly display variables inside of html, no js required, when built up like the following:

given the URL `https://myurl.com/link?key=HFEQ67fWE2`

`<p>{{ key }}</p>` will set the `<p>.textContent` to the value of the arg `key` `HFEQ67fWE2`

Can someone please help me how to use this feature consistently?

I was trying to understand how exactly to use this feature because after a bit more work on my project it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Since this is in Flask context, they're [Jinja variable placeholders](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#variables).

Answer (score 2):

The `{{ }}` **in Flask are used for template variable interpolation**.

Flask uses the Jinja2 template engine under the hood. Jinja2 uses `{{ }}` as the **syntax for variables and expressions that get replaced with values when a template is rendered**.

In a Flask view function, you can pass variables to a template using the `render_template()` method. For example:

```py
@app.route('/') 
def index():
  name = 'John'
  return render_template('index.html', name=name)
```

Then in the template (*index.html*), you can use `{{ name }}` to insert the value of the name variable:

```html
<p>Hello {{ name }}!</p>
```

When the template is rendered, `{{ name }}` will be replaced with 'John' in this case.

However, double curly braces allow you to insert any variables, expressions, filters etc in a template.

Check this out:

- [Jinja2 Variables](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#variables)
- [Flask Context Processors](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/templating/#context-processors)

Answer (score 1):

They have no meaning in HTML.

Various template languages (which can be used to output HTML) use them, including Jinja2 (the default template language for Flask, which you tagged).

The [documentation is here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/).

> `{{ ... }}` for Expressions to print to the template output